# Do redis streams scale when creating a new stream per client

Tags: redis, microservices

I am attempting to create a microservice where clients are connected to a certain service `A` over a TCP connection and a variety of actions are performed on other services within the microservice system (say `B, C, D` etc.) based on user interaction or other events, and I need to propagate results from these services `B, C, D` back to service `A` to be returned to the client.

Since many of these services perform long lived actions, is using redis streams as a buffer to store results from `B, C, D` to then be propagated to the client by `A` make sense? Considering a new different redis key is used for each client, will this scale well for thousands of connections? Is redis the right choice for event propagation on a `1:1` basis like this?

Kafka seems like a bad choice because all consumers are delivered every single message. Does it make sense to use something like ActiveMQ instead?